# Custom plugin - beans not injecting into controllers when deployed in war

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a problem in a plugin I am writing. I have a class that programmatically builds up 'bean references' to be injected into Spring. The beans are being injected but they are not available within controllers/services when deployed in a WAR (appears to work fine using run-app) unless I do grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('beanName').

A snippet of my GrailsPlugin file is shown below (I've amended it slightly here so any syntax errors are a red-herring):

```
def loadAfter = ['controllers', 'domains', 'services']

def doWithSpring = {
  beanDefinitionBuilder(BeanDefinitionBuilder, ref('classLoader'), application)
}  

def doWithApplicationContext = { ctx ->
  BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = ctx.beanDefinitionBuilder
  def beans = beans {
    for (String myBean : builder.getBeanNames()) {                  
        "${myBean}"(builder:"getService") { bean ->
          bean.autowire = 'byName'
        }
    }
  }
  beans.registerBeans(ctx)
}
```

Does anyone know why this would work for run-app but not for war or if what I am doing is entirely wrong, what approach I should take instead. I did originally have the entire code in the 'doWithSpring' block but I need to load resources and so I needed the ResourceLoader (made available by implementing ResourceLoaderAware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. I did try what nickdos mentioned above but this did not work. Instead, I managed to resolve my resource loading issue within the war and moved the spring injection code into the 'doWithSpring' closure. It now injects correctly when using run-app, in test environments and in a war.

Answer (score 0):

We had some issues with apps behaving differently as a deployed war file vs via run-app. The culprit was forked compilation which we turned off by editing `BuildConfig.groovy` thus:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    test: false,
    run: false,
    war: false,
    console: false
]
```

I'm not sure of the consequences of doing this (to the rest of the Grails app) as I was not responsible for the change, so YMMV.